# error on registration page and one page checkout after updating magento

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, register

I updated my Magento store from version 1.6 to 1.9 everything is working fine except when i click on proceed to checkout and choose one option checkout as guest or register user after filling the form when I click continue a pop up message generate and `"Storeowner" is a required value., "Storetype" is a required value.` and after clicking ok on that nothing will be happen . so can anyone help me why I am getting this error as their is some Javascript file is missing or some important file is missing.

Comment: I wonder which values "Storeowner" and "Storetype" are. Did you add them to your checkout process or do they come from a 3rd party module? They're not default.

Comment: actually i am working on client project which is having the Magento version 1.6 earlier but before upgrading it to 1.9 i removed all the extension form it but don't know why this value is coming.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check if these exist as attributes.

Under Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes check if they exist as attributes called Storeowner or Storetype.

Then you will need to either remove them if applicable or just set them to not required under Properties->Values Required = No.